# Inheriting context variables inside custom template tags

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a django template with a context variable `myVar`, set in the view function.
This template also renders a custom simple template tag `{% myTemplateTag %}` that renders `myTemplate.html`

I want to use `myVar` inside the custom template tag that renders `myTemplate.html`.

Is there a way to inherit the context variables of my view function in the custom template tag? (without passing it explicitly as a parameter to the template tag)?

Comment: Do [`takes_context`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/custom-template-tags/) help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using simple_tag

Using [simple_tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags), just set `takes_context=True`:

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def current_time(context, format_string):
    timezone = context['timezone']
    return your_get_current_time_method(timezone, format_string)
```

### Using a custom template tag

Just use template.Variable.resolve(), ie.

```
foo = template.Variable('some_var').resolve(context)
```

See [passing variables to the templatetag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#passing-template-variables-to-the-tag):

> To use the Variable class, simply instantiate it with the name of the
>   variable to be resolved, and then call variable.resolve(context). So,
>   for example:
>
> ```
> class FormatTimeNode(template.Node):
>     def __init__(self, date_to_be_formatted, format_string):
>         self.date_to_be_formatted = template.Variable(date_to_be_formatted)
>         self.format_string = format_string
>
>     def render(self, context):
>         try:
>             actual_date = self.date_to_be_formatted.resolve(context)
>             return actual_date.strftime(self.format_string)
>         except template.VariableDoesNotExist:
>             return ''
> ```
>
> Variable resolution will throw a VariableDoesNotExist exception if it cannot resolve the string passed
>   to it in the current context of the page.

Might be useful too: [setting a variable in the context](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#setting-a-variable-in-the-context).

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate and well thought out response! It helped me solve my issue perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could `include` the `myTemplate.html` file instead of rendering it with a special tag? Have you looked at the [include](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#include) tag? If you `include` `myTemplate.html` it will share the context with the one including it.